# read_only but still populated in create method on serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom create method on my serializer for adding tags where the consumer could solely send a payload with the `tags` key containing a list of tags' names.

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Testing",
...
"tags": ["Python", "Django", "Go"]
}
```

**Serializer:**

```py
class StreamSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    streamer = StreamerSerializer()
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Stream
        fields = [
            "id",
            "source",
            "stream_id",
            "started_at",
            "collected_at",
            "title",
            "thumbnail_url",
            "viewer_count",
            "video_type",
            "language",
            "streamer",
            "stream_data",
            "tags",
            "live_now",
        ]

        extra_kwargs = {"tags": {"validators": []}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # pop streamer and tags from the payload
        print(validated_data)
        streamer_data = validated_data.pop("streamer")
        tag_names = validated_data.pop("tags")

        # get_or_create the streamer for this stream
        streamer_user_id = streamer_data.pop("user_id")
        streamer, created = Streamer.objects.get_or_create(
            user_id=streamer_user_id, defaults=streamer_data
        )

        # use get_or_create on the stream to prevent duplicates if stream
        # crashes or a node change and just update the existing stream
        # with new data instead.
        stream, created = Stream.objects.get_or_create(
            streamer=streamer, defaults=validated_data
        )

        # add tags to the newly created stream
        for tag_name in tag_names:
            tag = Tag.objects.get(name=tag_name)
            stream.tags.add(tag.id)

        stream.save()
        return stream
```

I would like for tags to have `read_only=True`, but by doing this I get a `KeyError` when posting to this endpoint since this is now excluded from any write methods.

```py
class StreamSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    streamer = StreamerSerializer()
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) # add read_only
    ...
```

What could I do in order to not have tags necessary to validate, but still have access to the field in my `create` method? Would I need a custom validator for this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but does achieve the goal I'm going for using `to_internal_value` on my `TagSerializer`.

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    parent = ParentTagSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ["name", "aliases", "parent"]

        extra_kwargs = {"aliases": {"validators": []}}

    # to_internal_value will iterate each tag name in the post payload
    # and return the tag matching that name.
    def to_internal_value(self, tag_name):
        tag = Tag.objects.get(name=tag_name)
        return tag


class StreamSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    streamer = StreamerSerializer()
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    ...
```